# machine type does not support if=pflash,bus=0,unit=0

Tags: assembly, arm, gnu, qemu, gnu-assembler

I am using Qemu-system-arm for simulating arm environment to test some assembly codes. This is my main.S file:

```
.text
    ldr r0,=0x22000000
    mov r1,#1
    str r1,[r0]
```

This is my makefile:

```
TOOLCHAIN=arm-none-eabi
Assembler=${TOOLCHAIN}-as
Linker=${TOOLCHAIN}-ld
Objcpy=${TOOLCHAIN}-objcopy
Compile_Options= -g
Link_Options=-Tmain.lds
.PHONY : clean
.PRECIOUS : %.bin %.elf %.o
all : create

create : flash.bin 

flash.bin:main.bin  
    #dd if=/dev/zero of=flash.bin bs=4096 count=4096    
    dd if=/dev/zero of=flash.bin bs=4096 count=16   
    dd if=main.bin of=flash.bin bs=4096 conv=notrunc

%.bin:%.elf
    $(Objcpy) -O binary $< $@   

%.elf:%.o
    $(Linker) $(Link_Options) -o $@ $<

%.o:%.S
    $(Assembler) $(Compile_Options) $< -o $@
    
clean :
    rm -f *.o *.bin *.elf
```

and this is my qemu launcher script:

```
make clean
make
qemu-system-arm -S -M lm3s811evb -pflash flash.bin -nographic -serial /dev/null
```

I got this error:

```
qemu-system-arm: -pflash flash.bin: machine type does not support if=pflash,bus=0,unit=0
```